# Why don't function keys work natively with Windows?

Tags: windows, laptop, function-keys

I did a fresh install of Windows so I don't have any programs that use the function keys provided by the manufacturer.

When I turn on my laptop at the bios stage I can control the screen brightness with function keys but this does not work in Windows.

Why not, and is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Basically it boils down to: you'll need a tool from the manufacturer which you can either get on the CD/DVD that was included (if one was even included) or otherwise hopefully it's still downloadable from their website. Add which laptop maker/model to your question and someone can hopefully help further :)

Comment: Why do they work at the bios stage, but not in Windows? If they work at the bios stage they should work in windows without needing any special driver. My laptop is an Asus V1V and there is no windows 7 64bit software available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably does. The function keys are usually a BIOS thing that has to be enabled in the OS to work, usually with software the computer company provides. Google `<your computer make and model> drivers` and you'll probably get some result.

Comment: No, I have no software available for my version of windows. WHy would it work in the BIOS stage and not after the OS has loaded? I can't imagine why the OS would do something to disable functionality that works at a lower level. For things like volume control maybe...but screen brightness?

Comment: It's not disabling it, it just doesn't have the right software to handle it. In other words, there are such things as keyboard drivers. It's just a matter of recognizing the unique codes that the keys emit (different for every make) and interpreting them into keypresses.

Comment: I should rephrase my question so it is clearer. If the function keys work at the BIOS level, why would they then need a driver for the OS? For example the function keys to switch my my output between LCD and whatever work fine without drivers. The fact that brightness controls work at the BIOS level and not in windows indicates that Windows is doing something that negates them from working, not that I need a driver.

Comment: The BIOS can be thought of as a meta-operating system. It has its own drivers and so on. Similarly, some old computers can't boot from USB even though Windows can read USBs. Just a matter of drivers really.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that once the bios driver for the function keys is loaded it would stay loaded, right? I mean, why then can I switch between LCD and TV with function keys without a driver, but not control the brightness? I should also note that I was able to control the brightness with function keys without drivers on w732bit, it just seems not to work on 64bit.

Comment: What is your computer model?

Comment: Asus V1V, but please don't go looking for drivers. That is not what I am after. I am curious why it works at one stage and then not at a later stage....actually, maybe I should have posted this on SO instead...

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Like I said above, it's basically fragmentation between Microsoft and ASUS. ASUS doesn't actually help Microsoft make Windoze run better on ASUS which means that ASUS computers don't work perfectly in sync with Windows.

Comment: OK, but why would some function key functionaly work and not others? Obviously stuff like play and pause definitly needs drivers, and sometimes volume does. But on most laptops I see brightness working without drivers, and then without exception switching from lcd to tv always works without drivers. So if switching from lcd to tv can always work why can't brightness?

Comment: Brightness in specific is a signal routed to the BIOS which handles the command. Windows can't interface with the BIOS without the drivers and stuff.

Comment: Lol, come to think of it I don't think ASUS really knows why either.

Comment: But again, then why does the switching to LCD or TV work without a driver?

Comment: also turning on or off wireless or bluetooth via function keys  works without a driver...

Comment: Switching to an external monitor deals with the video card, not the BIOS. The brightness is a BIOS thing. As I said, it's a very specific per-model thing.

Comment: So if switching display deals with video card and not through bios, why can I switch on and off wireless nad bluetooth without driverS? brightness is the only thing not working, and it has worked previously without drivers.

Comment: I can't say any more really than that it's a stupid thing that computer makers do. Why can't you  use the webcam without turning on the light next to it?

Comment: My pleasure. (15 character minimum)